# How to detect control + v for pasting

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to C#.  I am using the following code to detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> when pressed on the keyboard:

```
while(true)
{
    bool check = (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl));

    if (check && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.V))
    {
        if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
            history.Dispatcher.Invoke(new invoke_method2(update2), 
                                      new object[] { Clipboard.GetText(), history });
    }
}
```

The program is running in the background. The problem is, it works when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then <kbd>v</kbd>. But the conditions also stand true if the user presses <kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, which is an unwanted trigger. Is there a way to overcome it?

Comment: I think that using while(true) loop is not the best idea... It is really heavy. Are you using Windows forms?

Comment: I am testing it on WPF and the loop is being run on a separate thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To capture a shortcut in a window in WPF, implement a KeyDown event, so creating a new thread isn't necessary:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    KeyDown += MainWindow_KeyDown;
}

void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.V)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

If you want to go with your solution, then you're practically searching for a point in time when <kbd>V</kbd> isn't pressed, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is, so the following works:

```
while (true)
{
    if (!Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.V))
    {
        while (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
        {
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.V))
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but i guess that would work only if my WPF window is active. I need to detect control + V globally.